# Irreducible components of the vanishing set of a single polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Assume the field $\mathbb{K}$, we're working with is algebraically closed. Let $V\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ be an irreducible affine variety. Suppose the coordinate ring $\mathbb{K}[V]$ is NOT a UFD. Choose $f\in \mathbb{K}[V]$ and suppose the factorization of  $f$ into its irreducible factors is $f=f_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots f_r^{\alpha_r}$. Then, $\mathcal{V}(f)=\mathcal{V}(f_1)\cup\dotsb\cup\mathcal{V}(f_r)$. But, is it still true that $\mathcal{V}(f_i)$'s are all the irreducible components of $\mathcal{V}(f)$?

I know this is true if $\mathbb{K}[V]$ is a UFD.

Comment: What does it mean to have "the factorization of $f$ into its irreducible factors" when you're not in a UFD? You also don't necessarily have that irreducible elements generate prime ideals in non-UFDs: take $2\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, for instance. So $V(f_i)$ might not be irreducible. I think you need to make some improvements to this question.

Comment: @KReiser What I meant was, suppose we know some factorization of $f$, where $f_i$'s happen to be irreducible.

Comment: You would need that the $f_i$ are prime in order to get that $V(f_i)$ are irreducible. But there's no reason for irreducible elements to be prime in general rings. (There are classes of rings where these two things coincide - UFDs and GCD domains, for instance, but this is special.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example: consider the [hyperboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) with one sheet of equation
$$x^2 + y^2 = z^2 + 1$$

There exist lines lying on this surface, for instance

$$x =  \frac{4}{5} z+\frac{3}{5}\\
y =   \frac{3}{5} z -\frac{4}{5}$$

Notice that the intersection of the surface with the plane $x - \frac{4}{5} z - \frac{3}{5}$ consists of two lines, the one above and
$$x =  \frac{4}{5} z+\frac{3}{5}\\
y =   -\frac{3}{5} z +\frac{4}{5}$$

It is not hard to see that the element $f = x - \frac{4}{5} z - \frac{3}{5}$ is irreducible in the ring of functions of the surface ( a quadratic extension of a ring of polynomials).  Of course, it is not prime, since we have the decomposition
$$(x-\frac{4}{5} z - \frac{3}{5}) (x+\frac{4}{5} z + \frac{3}{5}) = -(y  +\frac{3}{5} z-\frac{4}{5} )(y-\frac{3}{5} z+\frac{4}{5})$$